# Install OpenSSH with older OpenSSL version

Tags: server, ssh, openssh, openssl

For educational purposes, on Ubuntu Server 18.04 I've downloaded OpenSSH_7.6p1 4-Ubuntu0.1 which should be exposed to SSH enumeration.

**When I run ./configure, it says there's a problem with the OpenSSL version.**

If on my Ubuntu I run

```
openssl version
```

I get

```
OpenSSL 1.1.1 11 Sep 2018
```

And this version is not compatible with OpenSSH 7.6p1.

But, if I install OpenSSH via

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

it installs, and openssh version says:

```
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.7, **OpenSSL 1.0.2n 7 Dec 2017**
```

How can I use that OpenSSL version for my manual installation of OpenSSH too?

Thanks

Comment: Would you mind editing your question and indicating the Ubuntu version in use? The OpenSSL version(s) will probably vary depending on the OS version.

Comment: @DanielM., I'm using Ubuntu Server 18.04, I've edited the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenSSH 7.6p1 is an older version of OpenSSH which does not support the newer versions of OpenSSL like 1.1+. If you want to specifically compile that version of OpenSSH and not a newer version (the latest is 9.0p1 by the way), you should be able to fix your issue by installing the OpenSSL 1.0 development headers like this (note that this package is only available in Ubuntu 18.04 and below, and not available in Ubuntu 20.04 or above):

```
sudo apt install libssl1.0-dev
```

Do note that it conflicts with `libssl-dev` (OpenSSL 1.1 development headers), so if you need `libssl-dev` for building another package, you'd need to reinstall it afterwards. However `-dev` packages are only used for compiling software and are usually not required at runtime, so this shouldn't matter too much.

Hopefully this fixes your issue.

Comment: And btw, why do I see  `OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.7, OpenSSL 1.0.2n 7 Dec 2017` when running  `ssh -V `, and why with apt-get install  `openssh-server ` the installation has success?

Comment: this worked, thank you @DanielM. Just want to ask, now that I've all thes libssl-dev and libssl1.0 dev package installed, should I remove them?

Comment: @testermaster 1. That's the version of OpenSSL that the OpenSSH build is linked against. 2. apt install works because unlike development packages, the actual libs themselves don't conflict since they have separate soname versions (libssl.so.1.0 can exist alongside libssl.so.1.1). 3. You can remove the packages if you don't plan to build any other software needing them, however they do no harm to keep.